# How to add config file for config file provider plugin with groovy script in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am using [Job DSL](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) in Jenkins. There is a [seed job](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Tutorial---Using-the-Jenkins-Job-DSL) that generates some files that should be shared across other jobs that could run on different nodes. If the files were not generated, the [config files provider plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin) could be used for this task. However I need the files to be dynamic so that no Jenkins UI interaction is needed.

Is it possible to add a file to the plugin with a groovy script?

The only other option I could think of was to record the UI interaction and let a script replay it with modified data. In case of a more secured Jenkins this would also require to get authentication and CSRF tokens right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Job DSL to create config files that are managed by the Config File Provider plugin:

```
configFiles {
    customConfig {
        id('one')
        name('Config 1')
        comment('lorem')
        content('ipsum')
        providerId('???')
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands#config-file

Answer (score 3):

When you are using job-dsl you can read in data from anywhere that the Groovy runtime can access.

You could store shared config in a hard coded variable in your script itself.

You could inject the data via a Jenkins parameter to your seed job.

You could retrieve the data from a file in the git repo where your store your seed job.

You could retrieve the data from a database, REST API.

etc etc.